# Is there a clever shortcut to showing that this function is in O(N^2)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, quadratics

This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

I am currently working on 2a.

I am trying to apply an example the book gave earlier 
[image]

Is there some similar clever trick I can apply to 2a to shorten the math I would have to do?
Here is the work I have so far 
[image]

I prefer not to go through the quadratic equation solver http://www.mathsisfun.com/quadratic-equation-solver.html and getting some floating point value but i can't find something like  x > 7 for 17x + 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that $17x+11$ is $O(x^2)$.

This is easiest if you *don't* start with deciding on a constant factor, but instead start by finding a suitable lower bound for the inequality.

For example, suppose $x>11$. Then

$$ \tag{*} 17x+11 < 17x+x < 18x $$

Hmm, this would be less than $x^2$ if only $x>18$. But since $18>11$, all of (*) is still true for $x>18$, so we can change our mind and say that for $x>18$ we have

$$ 17x+11 < 17x+x < 18 x < x^2 $$

Thus we can conclude that $17x+11=O(x^2)$ because $17x+11\le 1\cdot x^2$ for all $x>18$.
This is not the "best possible" constants, but in order to prove the result it is enough to find a set that *works*.

Comment: yeah i guess the key is to come up with some interval and then reason with it.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the choices of $C$ and $k$ witnesses are not unique.

The answer to the first problem is **yes** since 
$$
17x+11\leq 17x+x = 18x\leq 18x^2
$$
for all $x>11$. The witnesses are $C=18$ and $k=11$.

Comment: yeah this is so much more clear than the neverending floating point value i got.

Comment: so the key is to come up with some interval?

Answer (score 0):

The function $h\colon x \in [1,\infty) \mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ goes to $0$, as
$$\frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \frac{17x+11}{x^2} \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0.$$
Having a limit at $\infty$ (and by continuity) $h$ is bounded, and in particular there exists $C > 0$ such that, for all $x \geq 1$, $\frac{f(x)}{x^2} \geq C$. Equivalently, $f(x) \leq C x^2$ for all $x \geq 1$, proving that $f(x)=O(x^2)$.

Comment: so C can be any C?

Comment: You don't need to have the *explicit* value, you only need to prove that there exists *one* that works.